# Upload file from browser with Aws s3 JavaScript

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

Does AWS s3 js upload sdk files directly from browser to s3 bucket?
I am currently using the Php SDK
I uploaded the files to the server first and then uploaded them to the s3 bucket
but this process consumes too much resources
I could not find an example on the web
I'm waiting for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files directly from your browser using AWS S3 JavaScript SDK.

- One approach is to implement a mechanism to request for temporary access credentials directly or indirectly from AWS STS to assume an AWS IAM role that allows S3 upload.
- Another approach is to generate [AWS S3 Presigned Post](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) using AWS S3 SDK from a backend that sends temporary access credentials to upload content to a private bucket.

For more details check the [Examples: Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST (Using AWS Signature Version 4)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

Comment: Hello there
thanks for your answer Do you have a video for that? I think I need a very complicated video

Comment: I don't have a video for it, but just updated the answer with an example using a simpler approach using temporary access credentials.

Comment: I have written a medium article just now, it might help to implement it https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-signed-urls-fa0a0cf489db

Comment: Thanks for the article
I am starting to examine